# Jboss 4.3 EAP in Eclipse asks credentials on server startup

Tags: eclipse, jboss

I am using eclipse Galileo and I am trying to start my JBoss 4.3 EAP.

When I start JBOSS from command line it runs fine. But when I start it from eclipse I get

the following pop up and my application is not deployed

```
    your server is repsonding to jmx queries with a security exception.
you can try entering new credentials below or you can double click on your server and verify the host, jndi port, username and password are accurate.
you can also click ignore below to begin working with your server but deploying to and stopping the server may not function properly
```

My jboss from command line and my Eclipse both use the same jre

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JBoss EAP by default the JMX Console has turn on security domain and you need provide proper user and password to login in. But the default user is disabled .

You can turn in on by editing the `$JBOSS_HOME/server/default/conf/props/jmx-console-users.properties` (for `default` profile).

You can just uncomment the `admin` user or add your own (in that case also edit `jmx-console-roles.properties` file).